# -(void)onMapRendered: (NTBitmap*)mapBitmap is not called

Tags: nutiteq

In iOS platform

-(void)onMapRendered: (NTBitmap*)mapBitmap

is not called in case of offline maps and if [NTMapView captureRendering:] is called with waitWhileUpdating:YES. Is there any common solutions on this matter? Or maybe there should be some specific init of NTMapRenderListener?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it seems to work fine in both online and offline cases. No special initialisation code is necessary, overriding onMapRendered method is sufficient. Perhaps you can make a minimal (but complete) sample demonstrating the issue?